# PHP-FFMPeg is not processing files on CentOS server

Tags: php, ffmpeg, centos, ffmpeg-php

PHP-FFMPeg Version: 0.13.0

FFmpeg Version: N-95710-gb25b643

CentOS 7.7

**Actual Behavior**

We are using PHP-FFMPeg on laravel to process a video file to 720p and 480p.

The PHP-FFMPeg is not processing the file or generate a file with 0 bytes.

Sometimes one of this resolutions is precessed, most of the time is the 720p.

The Exception return "Encoding failed".

This occours only on production server CentOS.

Executing the command of FFmpeg on prompt of production server works well.

**Expected Behavior**

PHP-FFMPeg process a video file to 720p and 480p.

**Code**

We have two jobs of Laravel to process the files in chain.

In the ProcessVideo720PJob.php file: 
https://gist.github.com/Diego-MNG/e58228afe459dd65fcc58fb5970d627f#file-processvideo720pjob-php

In the ProcessVideo480PJob.php file: 
https://gist.github.com/Diego-MNG/e58228afe459dd65fcc58fb5970d627f#file-processvideo480pjob-php